# Simulating a join in ElasticSearch

Tags: join, elasticsearch

Assume there are documents in an ES index that have two fields, `user_id` and `action_id`. How to count users such that there are documents both with `action_id = 1` and `action_id = 2`?

Equivalent SQL would be

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `a`.`uuid`)
FROM `action` AS `a`
JOIN `action` AS `b` ON `a`.`user_id` = `b`.`user_id`
WHERE `a`.`action_id` = 1
AND `b`.`action_id` = 2
```

I found the only way to do so: request twice all unique `user_id`s with these `action_id`s and find intersection of resulting sets on the ES client. Yet this approach needs to transfer megabytes of data from ES, so I'm searching for an alternative.

Comment: You should probably look at parent - child relation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html

Comment: @slawek This is statistics information, so that it's getting in ES row by row. As I understood from the manual, addition of a child would require recreating the parent and all the children in ES. That's possibly several gigabytes worth of data.

Comment: Not sure where you got that. From the page I linked: "Child documents can be added, changed, or deleted without affecting either the parent or other children. This is especially useful when child documents are large in number and need to be added or changed frequently"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- first you have a query that filters your documents with actions `1` and `2` only (I have no idea if you can have other action types)
- then the magic is with aggregations

  - the first aggregation is a `terms` one for `user_id`, so that you can do individual calculations **per user**
  - then you use a `cardinality` sub-aggregation to count the number of distinct actions per user. Since the query is for actions `1` and `2` that number can only be 1 or 2
  - then you use a `bucket_selector` sub-aggregation to only keep those users that have the cardinality result of `2`.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "action_id": [
              1,
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "actions": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "action_id"
          }
        },
        "actions_count_bucket_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "totalActions": "actions"
            },
            "script": "totalActions >= 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result will look like this:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "users": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 1,
               "doc_count": 2,
               "actions": {
                  "value": 2
               }
            },
            {
               "key": 5,
               "doc_count": 2,
               "actions": {
                  "value": 2
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

The `key`s are the user_ids whose actions are `1` **and** `2`. `bucket_selector` aggregation is available in 2.x+ version of ES.

Comment: I tried that approach previously, it would work in most cases. There are some aggregations in ES that could be run over the result of another aggregation, and I've tried to get down to the single number in result (not successfully, though). Yet this approach couldn't work for me for the reasons I forgot to mention in the question, so I had to use `user_id` intersection approach.